# session override in .htaccess, and even php ini_set not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

**UPDATE**

**PHP ini settings**

Directive   | Local Value | Master Value

session.auto_start  Off Off

session.cache_expire    180 180

session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache

session.cookie_domain   no value    no value

session.cookie_httponly Off Off

session.cookie_lifetime 0   0

session.cookie_path /   /

session.cookie_secure   Off Off

session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom

session.entropy_length  32  32

session.gc_divisor  1   1

session.gc_maxlifetime  3   3

session.gc_probability  1   1

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

---

**ORIGINAL**

I have tried about 15 different methods, through resaearch and past stack overflow posts, and the result is still the same, I am logged out of the session after 5-10 mins of going inactive

All I want to achieve is to stay logged in for a long time...

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    #Session timeout
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime "3600000"
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime "3600000"
</IfModule>
```

**php**

```php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600000);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600000);
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("Location: admin-login.php");
    exit(); 
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && (time() - $_SESSION['username'] > 3600000)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['username'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

Comment: Could you expand on "I am logged out of the session after 5-10 mins"? This is a rather broad statement and you sound unsure about your own observations.

Comment: @Dharman I want to stay logged in for long period ...hence why I have set the time..... but I am logged out after 5 mins of going inactive

Comment: This has brought even more confusion... Could you please clearly explain your desired behavior and explain to us what is happening? Have you checked the cookie lifetime? Have you debugged your $_SESSION contents?

Comment: @Dharman I am wanting to be able to login...go inactive or not even do anything....and still stay logged in....

Comment: @Phil where will i check the log and I'm sure session_destory is not killing it, as I can access php pages....whilst logged in... but If i go inactive for 5-10 minutes it logs me out

Comment: You could also put a breakpoint and debug your code with a debugger to see what is happening, it is usually the best way to find your mistakes.

Comment: @Phil - I don't know the asnwer to your question, all I know it, I don't have access to php.ini file, and the php logs out (session) after 5-10mins

Comment: @Phil - your statement then

Comment: @Phil Thanks for that - I also dont have PHP / appache logs, my web server hosting/ provider is not so good

Comment: Then comment it out and wait 10 minutes.

Comment: good suggestion - @Dharman , I will do that now

Comment: okay @Dharman , i commented it out and as i went to the login page, it redirected me to the index.php as logged in.... without even logging in

Comment: @Dharman, after 10 minutes, I' am logged back out again.... with session_destory being removed

Comment: Then it is not because of your code. Check what settings are maintained for your PHP with [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). Look for a setting which could mean 10 minutes(e.g. 600 seconds). We can't guess from our side what is happening to your sessions.

Comment: If `phpinfo()` doesn't show the values you're setting in `.htaccess`, then that means it's not working. Are you sure it's using `mod_php7.c`? You could try removing the `<IfModule>`. Alternatively, try a [`.user.ini` file](http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php)

Comment: @Phil, I have made a php.ini file in my public_html, set the maxlifetime to 3 - for testing and the session should end theoretically after three seconds? it dosn't... changing that value in the .ini file seems to have done nothing.... I checked phpinfo() and the value updated correctly

Comment: Next thin I'd be looking at is the `expire` parameter on the cookie. Use your browser's _Network_ console to inspect the response from one of your `.php` pages

Comment: @Phil I tried that and nothing shows in the network console, In the phpinfo, the cookie value is set to 0 - to my knowledge means cookie wont expire until browser is closed?

Comment: *"Note: If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with session.save_path."* [gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) See also: [gc_probability](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) and [gc_divisor](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor)

Answer (score 1):

`ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600000);` sets the lifetime of session files for the currently running script only. If other scripts are startet, the have their own (default) setting. A session file is removed when its lifetime has expired *and the **garbage collection** is invoked*.

> Note: If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with **session.save_path**.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

This means that each script accessing the session folder, even foreign sites depending on shared hosting configuration, can have its own lifetime setting and therefore delete session files in the configured folder. Thus you should also set the `session.save_path` to a writeble folder under your control. All scripts accessing a session within that save path need to be configured with the intended settings. See also the PHP function [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php).

Further more the session garbage collection does not run on every script start by default. You can configue this by [session.gc_probability](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) and [session.gc_divisor](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor). Set both, probability and divisor, to `1`.

Note that passing an integer value to `ini_set` results into a fatal error. It should be a string value: `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '3600000');`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190068/discussion-on-answer-by-quasimodos-clone-session-override-in-htaccess-and-eve).